# How to return data from an array within an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following data that I parsed from an xml file and now I have a problem returning the data. How do i return the photo src data from the array within the photo array. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

**Code**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$photo_url = $xml['photo']->src;

for ($i=0, $n=count($photo_url); $i<$n; ++$i) {
    echo $photo_url[$i].'<br>';
}
```

**Data**

```
["photo"]=>
  array(46) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "26001"
        ["src"]=>
        string(36) "1006416.jpg"
        ["thumb"]=>
        string(42) "1006416_thumb.jpg"
        ["title"]=>
        string(16) "album"
        ["subtitle"]=>
        string(6) "01.jpg"
        ["favorite"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "26001"
        ["src"]=>
        string(36) "1006417.jpg"
        ["thumb"]=>
        string(42) "1006417_thumb.jpg"
        ["title"]=>
        string(16) "album"
        ["subtitle"]=>
        string(6) "02.jpg"
        ["favorite"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [SimpleXMLElement attributes](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method, like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach( $xml as $xml_node)
{
    $attributes = $xml_node->attributes();
    echo 'Photo source: ' . $attributes['src'] . "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/N5gqST)